# php array_diff not giving results

Tags: php, mysql, array-difference

Could someone please take a look and let me know what i'm doing wrong...
What i'm trying to acheive is, in the Database i have:

```
AGENT_REF = 1
AGENT_REF = 2
AGENT_REF = 3
AGENT_REF = 4
AGENT_REF = 5
```

In a file uploaded that parses information

```
$blmarArray = array($agentref);

AGENT_REF = 1
AGENT_REF = 2
AGENT_REF = 3
AGENT_REF = 5
```

What i'd like to happen is to extract the AGENT_REF from the database that ISN'T in the file uploaded, in this case AGENT_REF = 4 so i can DELETE it from mysql.

```
$sql_archeck = mysql_query("SELECT `AGENT_REF` FROM `eprentals`");
$archeck = mysql_fetch_array($sql_archeck);
$sqlarArray = array($archeck);
$combyArrayDiff = array_diff($blmarArray, $sqlarArray);
print_r ($combyArrayDiff);
```

All i'm getting is the last or first AGENT REF from the database and not the ones that arn't present in the db.
(In the db there is 11 but the file uploaded only 8 are present, so i'd like to delete (SHOW) the ones that are in the DB that have been removed from the file uploaded)

Hope you can offer me some guidance into where i'm wrong with this and I Thank you for your time and appriciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from php manual:

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not
>   present in any of the other arrays.

so insted of `array_diff($blmarArray, $sqlarArray)` you should use `array_diff($sqlarArray, $blmarArray)`

= the big array as first parameter, and the samller array as 2nd parameter

---

you also need to fetch all rows from the database, not just the first

```
$query = "SELECT `AGENT_REF` FROM `eprentals`";
$resource = mysql_query($query);
$sqlarArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_archeck))
{
    $sqlarArray[] = $row['AGENT_REF'];
}
$combyArrayDiff = array_diff($sqlarArray, $blmarArray);

/* debug result */
echo "<p><b>SQL list:</b> " . implode(', ', $sqlarArray) . "</p>";
echo "<p><b>Uploaded list:</b> " . implode(', ', $blmarArray) . "</p>";
echo "<p><b>Diff list:</b> " . implode(', ', $combyArrayDiff ) . "</p>";
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your speedy responce, This is showing the first row in the db which is present in the file uploaded.. for eg it shows AGENT_REF = 1 and not AGENT_REF = 4 :)

Comment: Just to show my results... :)
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 53384_3 [AGENT_REF] => 53384_3 ) )
Where it should be 53384_7 thats the difference :) The 53384_3 is the first one in the database

Comment: you only fetch one row, you don't using a fetch loop

Comment: Hi Puggen Se, Thank you very much for your time, not there yet but i'm thinking now as i can see results that i'm not getting all the blm results as the diff list is the same as the sql list yet the blm file list is the first one 53384_3 :)
I greatly appriciate your time with me thank you:)

Comment: are you sure you loading the $blmarArray correctly, dose a print_r at it looks as expected?

Comment: I don't think i am to be honest, On print_r it shows the Last AGENTREF in the file... ie: 11.
this
     $agentref = $values[0]; gets the AGENT_REF Values no problems, not showing an array to do the array diff...

    $agentref = $values[0];
    $blmarArray = array($agentref);

Comment: go read abit about arrays, maybe this article: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php6p2.html good luck

Comment: lol was just on the php manual... Thank you so much for putting me on right path with this, greatly appriciated :)